# Do electrum fully support Hierarchical Deterministic Wallets?

Tags: wallet, address, electrum, bip32-hd-wallets

I'm curious if electrum fully support Hierarchical Deterministic Wallets (BIP32). I have seen in source code that some part of implementation is done. But there are also as I think some electrum specific algorithms.

So when I create new wallet in electrum will it be BIP32 compatible?

Comment: related: [What is the status of hierarchical deterministic wallets (BIP32)](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4992/5406)

Comment: Of course I have seen it before asking this question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIP32 support is planned for Electrum version 2.0. The code is already there, but disabled.

You can find some features that were first planned for 2.0, but were included in a 1.9.8 release as the servers were being updated to a new important version so it was needed to apply some changes already to the client to put all in place for 2.0 https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=518133.0

Comment: I have one additional question. You are saying "BIP32 (or a similar approach but not standard)" so BIP32 isn't the standard?

Comment: @Adam I've updated the answer with the latest update from devs. Electrum will use BIP32 standard for 2.0 version

Comment: @rdymac Can you update the answer as of now. It's 2017 now so probably the new visitors to the question will be grateful to get an updated answer.