# What current wallets support deterministic public addresses (BIP32)?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

Just curious how many complete implementations of the bip32 standard exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the status of hierarchical deterministic wallets (BIP32)](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/what-is-the-status-of-hierarchical-deterministic-wallets-bip32)

Answer (score 1):

I know of these three:

- The [Gem API](https://gem.co/) enables wallets to be made using their BIP32 compliant API.
- There is also the [BitGo](https://www.bitgo.com/) service that uses BIP32 Multisig wallets.
- [BitStash](http://www.bitstash.com/) hardware wallets also are BIP 32 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

there is a list of implementations [in the bip32 documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#implementations):

> Two Python implementations exist:
>
> PyCoin (https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin) is a suite of utilities
>   for dealing with Bitcoin that includes BIP0032 wallet features.
>   BIP32Utils (https://github.com/jmcorgan/bip32utils) is a library and
>   command line interface specifically focused on BIP0032 wallets and
>   scripting.
>
> A Java implementation is available at
>   https://github.com/bitsofproof/supernode/blob/1.1/api/src/main/java/com/bitsofproof/supernode/api/ExtendedKey.java
>
> A C++ implementation is available at
>   https://github.com/CodeShark/CoinClasses/tree/master/tests/hdwallets
>
> An Objective-C implementation is available at
>   https://github.com/oleganza/CoreBitcoin/blob/master/CoreBitcoin/BTCKeychain.h
>
> A Ruby implementation is available at
>   https://github.com/GemHQ/money-tree
>
> Two Go implementations exist:
>
> hdkeychain
>   (https://github.com/conformal/btcutil/tree/master/hdkeychain) provides
>   an API for bitcoin hierarchical deterministic extended keys (BIP0032).
>   Go HD Wallet (https://github.com/WeMeetAgain/go-hdwallet).
>
> Two JavaScript implementations exist: available at
>   https://github.com/sarchar/brainwallet.github.com/tree/bip32 and
>   https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore
>
> A PHP implemetation is available at
>   https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-lib-php
>
> A C# implementation is available at
>   https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin (ExtKey, ExtPubKey)
>
> A Haskell implementation is available at
>   https://github.com/haskoin/haskoin together with a CLI interface at
>   https://github.com/np/hx

**you should [check the documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#implementations) rather than relying on my copy here though, since my copy will go out of date over time**

Answer (score 0):

Well I know that Wallet32 on android is compatible with trezor and they both use BIP32. Darkwallet is another along with Electrum. Armory is another. GreenAddress.it. That's all I know.

Comment: Armory does not use BIP-32, it uses a [similar](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/issues/204), but incompatible key derivation algorithm. Seems there was [some work](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/pull/161) done, but I cannot find any indication that this is available in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

### Python

- PyCoin (https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin) is a suite of utilities for dealing with Bitcoin that includes BIP0032 wallet features.
- BIP32Utils (https://pypi.org/project/bip32utils/) is a library and command line interface specifically focused on BIP0032 wallets and scripting.
- btc_hd_wallet (https://github.com/scgbckbone/btc-hd-wallet) easy to use python HD (paper) wallet implementation.

### Java

- https://github.com/bitsofproof/supernode/blob/1.1/api/src/main/java/com/bitsofproof/supernode/api/ExtendedKey.java
- https://github.com/bushidowallet/bushido-java-core/tree/master/src/main/java/com/bushidowallet/core/bitcoin/bip32

### C++

- https://github.com/ciphrex/mSIGNA/blob/master/deps/CoinCore/src/hdkeys.h

### Objective-C

- https://github.com/oleganza/CoreBitcoin/blob/master/CoreBitcoin/BTCKeychain.h

### Ruby

- https://github.com/GemHQ/money-tree

### Go

- hdkeychain (https://github.com/conformal/btcutil/tree/master/hdkeychain) provides an API for bitcoin hierarchical deterministic extended keys (BIP0032).
- Go HD Wallet (https://github.com/WeMeetAgain/go-hdwallet).

### JavaScript

- https://github.com/sarchar/brainwallet.github.com/tree/bip32
- https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore

### PHP

- https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-lib-php

### C#

- https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin (ExtKey, ExtPubKey)

### Haskell

- https://github.com/haskoin/haskoin together with a CLI interface at https://github.com/np/hx

Comment: This was originally taken from the BIP, where it was removed in https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/962